# Weird character when converting ByteArray to String in Java

Tags: java

I have the following byte array `private byte[] file = new byte[40]`.

It takes in a String of a maximum of 20 characters. If it is shorter, the rest of the array is padded with zeroes:

```
[116, 111, 117, 99, 104, 50, 46, 116, 120, 116, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This byte sequence is transferred using Java's socket and converted back to a String to be used as a filepath.

However, after truncating the zeroes and using `String filePath = new String(path);` yields a weird character at the back of the string:

```
Appending to this file.. touch2.txt╚
```

Method for truncating:

```
 private byte[] trim(byte[] bytes){
        int i = bytes.length - 1;
        while (i >= 0 && bytes[i] == 0)
        {
            --i;
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(bytes, i + 1);
    }
```

How do I get rid of this character? Strangely printing the original byte array and the truncated one gives the same sequence of characters.

Comment: Arent that character a system escape showing the breakpoint character? try appending a string at the end to see if it moves

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Why would you expect something different? The byte `3` converts to this character on a single byte encoding.

Comment: Although I am not entirely sure what encoding you are using. With UTF-8 this (`╚`) character converts to `9562`. But the general idea is: In your encoding `3` is this character. So your problem is not trimming wrongly but having a `3` in there that you seemingly don't want to have.

Comment: Try to clear the array before loading the string into it...

Comment: You can use `new String(base, 0).trim()` which removes these characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After truncating all of the 0 bytes you still have the byte **3** at the end of the sequence which is most probably being displayed like this: ╚. Maybe the *end of text byte* (i.e **3**) should not be present in your sequence, or maybe the truncate method should truncate that character as well.